# Blackjack println game Java programming

Tags: java, blackjack

I have a problem with my dealerhand method in my blackjack game.

I have a method to produce a random card from the class deck.

The cards have assigned values to them and so forth.
however the problem lies in the code where i want the dealer to draw a new card, and add the value to the existing total hand value. the code is a following.

//Basics for the values of dealers cards

```
    int dealerHandValue = 0;
    int tempDealerHandValue = 0;
    int totalDealerHandValue= 0;
```

//Dealers first card

```
    randomGenNum = (int)((range * Math.random()) + 1)*2;
    dealerHandValue = arrayCardRank[randomGenNum];
    CardSuit = arrayCardSuit[randomGenNum];


    System.out.println("Dealer First Card Shows : " + (CardSuit));

    tempDealerHandValue = dealerHandValue;
```

//Code executed when player stops drawing and stands.

```
           while (totalDealerHandValue < 18 && totalDealerHandValue <21)
           {

           randomGenNum = (int)((range * Math.random()) + 1)*2;
           dealerHandValue = arrayCardRank[randomGenNum];
           CardSuit = arrayCardSuit[randomGenNum];


           System.out.println("Dealer next Card Shows : " + (CardSuit));

           tempDealerHandValue = dealerHandValue;

           totalDealerHandValue = (tempDealerHandValue) + (dealerHandValue);

           System.out.println("Dealer total hand value is " + (totalDealerHandValue));

       }



       {
           System.out.println("Dealer stopped drawing");

           if (totalDealerHandValue >= totalUserHandValue)
           {

               System.out.println("Dealer wins");
               return;

           }
           else

               System.out.println("Congratulations! You Win!");
           return;


       }
```

This method will just add the new cards value to itself, on and on until the while statement ends.

i have gone blind on the problem, and i know it is easily fixed.
can anyone help me towards what i am missing?

Comment: what's the problem?  I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: i need the tempDealerHandValue to be added to the totalDealerHandValue , every time a new card is drawn until the while loop ends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're never incrementing totalDealerHandValue, just overwriting the value over and over again.

Replace these two lines:

```
tempDealerHandValue = dealerHandValue;

totalDealerHandValue = (tempDealerHandValue) + (dealerHandValue);
```

with

```
totalDealerHandValue += dealerHandValue;
```

Comment: Thanks ! this didnt work at first, i the method where dealer shows second card in order for this to work. Thanks again man! Really helped